# Download PDF base64 - Internet Explorer - Not asking to save

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, base64

I'm just trying to work this code in Internet Explorer. In Chrome and Firefox is ok, but on Internet Explorer is showing the message "Do you want to allow this website to open an app on your computer".

The Challenge is to download a PDF from a String Base64.

[image]

Then

[image]

JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/7prjvcun/

The code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body id="index" >
        <a target="_blank" id='dwnldLnk' download='nome-do-arquivo.pdf' href="javascript:void(0);">LINK </a> 
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var pdf = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' +
            'JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu' +
            ...

            'OTM4MjIvWFJlZlN0bSA5MzU2NT4+DQpzdGFydHhyZWYNCjk0MjU5DQolJUVPRg==';

            var dlnk = document.getElementById('dwnldLnk');
            dlnk.href = pdf;
            dlnk.click();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's a feature. It means reader is linked to Internet Explorer and IE is asking if this is save to open.

Comment: Ok, but the IE is not asking about save, it only have the option to open the PDF and not to save. And if the user have no one PDF reader, it ask to download software to open. Look the new image

Answer (score 0):

People, I discover in http://caniuse.com/#search=anchor, IE not suport the atributte download.

Now I will looking for a another way.

Comment: Have you managed to make it work?
It would be nice from to share your fix :)

Comment: Sorry @adam, I change of project and I dont remenber the resolution.